# How to make a panel slides to the left or right in java?

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a panel that slides to the left when a button is clicked. I hope if there's a swing component that does that. I made a sketch to illustrate my idea.

[image]

Comment: Looks like you're looking for [JSplitPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html). Call [setOneTouchExpandable(true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JSplitPane.html#setOneTouchExpandable%28boolean%29).

Comment: There is a similar question, which is answerd here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11425274/adding-animation-transitions-to-java-swing-containers

Comment: Take a look at [SlidingLayout](https://github.com/AurelienRibon/sliding-layout)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a `JSplitPane`. you could animate the position of the splitter  by adding/subtracting from the location and using Thread.sleep(millis goes here); to time each increment/decrements. I hope this works!